# Using private properties with Module Augmentation in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I was experimenting a bit the concept of [Module Augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) in Typescript.
I was trying to create a module that, when imported, injects a method into an object prototype (a class, in this case) created in another module.

My folder structure is the following:

```
.
├── DynamicAdvertising
│   ├── asTemporalSlots.ts
│   └── index.ts
└── index.ts
```

I wanted to achieve something like:

```js
import Personalisation from "./DynamicAdvertising";
/** Here Personalisation should not have the method 'asTemporalSlots' **/
import "./DynamicAdvertising/asTemporalSlots";
/** Here Personalisation should have it **/
```

`Personalisation` has the following structure:

```js
export default class Personalisation {
    /**
     * Constructor is not private on purpose.
     * We might want to use this class
     * just as a parser for a response
     * object that we already have.
     */

    constructor(private response: Response) {}

    static async fetch(request: PersonalisationRequest<any>) {
        if (!(request instanceof PersonalisationRequest)) {
            throw new Error('Wrong request. Cannot proceed.');
        }

        const response = await fetch(request);
        return new Personalisation(response);
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

So I'm creating the instace through a static method.
According to several other threads here on StackOverflow and the page itself, to extend Personalisation in `asTemporalSlots`, I have to do this (and this works fine):

```js
import Personalisation from ".";

declare module "." {
    export default interface Personalisation {
        asTemporalSlots(this: Personalisation): any
    }
}

Personalisation.prototype.asTemporalSlots = async function asTemporalSlots(): AdvSlots[] {
    ...
}
```

And this is actually fine, I can extend without any issues. I can also use `this` to represent `Personalisation` instance.

The issue comes when I try to access to `this.response`, which is a `private` property in the class.

[image: cannot use private example]

If I add `asTemporalSlots` directly in `Personalisation`, I can use it without any issue. So, why I cannot use it when extending the prototype? What can I do, in your experience, to make this check pass? I'd like to keep response private if possible.

Thank you very much to everybody!

Comment: Did you try protected instead of private? (`constructor(protected response: Response) {}`)

Comment: @CodeStix different error: Property 'response' is protected and only accessible within class 'Personalisation' and its subclasses. (ts 2445)

Comment: I feel like this is an inappropriate limitation in typescript's design, accessing a private/protected member really is an common operation when writing module augmentations. you could write an suggestion in the typescript GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/new/choose).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string indexing, which keeps type checking on `response`:

```
Personalisation.prototype.asTemporalSlots = async function asTemporalSlots() {
    let a = await this.response.json(); // <- error not accessible
    let b = await this["response"].json(); // <- ok
};
```

Typescript does not check the modifiers on a class field when you access it via string indexing. This works because a class instance is just an object with a set prototype, and javascript does not have private class members.

Or use `as any` (this removes type checking on `response`):

```
Personalisation.prototype.asTemporalSlots = async function asTemporalSlots() {
    let c = (this as any).response.json();
};
```

Comment: Hm, using indexing is pretty hacky but weird to me. It works, but it is really weird typescript doesn't check it.
Using `as any` gets a big no for me.
I'll accept this as answer if nothing better will come up! Thanks!